# Python - Nested For Loops working unexpectedly

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop

I am coding a molecular dynamics simulation and within it I need to calculate the force between each atom based on their position.

The position is given as an 8 by 9 array. The following nested for loops are used to traverse this array such that only its upper triangle is consider to half the neccessary computation.

The code for this can be seen here:

```
position_x = np.array(random(9)*50)
position_y = np.array(random(9)*50)
position = np.array(list(zip(position_x, position_y)))
velocity_x = random(9)*5
velocity_y = random(9)*5

r = cdist(position, position , metric = 'euclidean')
d = r[r != 0] #Remove zeros from array, shape is lost
d_d = np.reshape(d,(8,9)) #Form 1D Array into 9, 8 element arrays
for i in range(len(position)):
  c = c + 1 
  for j in range(len(position) - c ):
    newxforce = []
    newxforce.append((-24)*((1/((d_d[i,j])**7))-(2/((d_d[i,j])**13)))*
    ((position_x[i] - position_x[i+1])))
```

This code should populate the newxforce array with new values but instead I am only attaining an array with  single value in it.

Any ideas on what could be going wrong ?

Comment: Inside `for j in range(len(position) - c ):` you have `newxforce = []`. You create an empty list on each iteration, and basically wipe whatever you had before. Take `newxforce = []` outside of the `for` loop.

Comment: That did it ! 
Thanks so much sir

Comment: You might also be able to get some use out of `np.triu_indices`, which would allow you to avoid using python for loops.